# Slow pdflatex in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: pdftex, ubuntu

I'm compiling the same 14000-pages file on a new X1 Gen 9 with ubuntu 20.04 and on an older X1 Gen 4 with ubuntu 16.04, the first is significantly slower (no other heavy tasks in parallel).  Some details are below.

Do you have any ideas or suggestions to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

```
Gen 9: 

real 14m23,594s
user 1m57,165s
sys 12m19,631s

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01

vs Gen 4:

real 2m15.146s
user 2m9.087s
sys 0m5.726s

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty. Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.41.0
```

Comment: possibly you have the tex search path set so it is searching a large filesystem directory tree without an ls-file, seaching for files can easily take longer than processing the tex in them.

Comment: The file consists of almost identical 14-pages sections, generated in loop, and the only altered part is the included graphics with a sort of QR code, one per page.  So all the style files and fonts are searched for in the very beginning, which takes few seconds. The path to included pdf images is set by \graphicspath from graphicx.sty

Comment: graphicspath can be slow especially if you onit the extensions from the filename, but basically you have not given any information so short of some wild guesses there is not a lot that can be said really

Comment: Consider this example:

`\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{mp-codes/600000.pdf}
\includegraphics{mp-codes/600001.pdf}
\includegraphics{mp-codes/600002.pdf}
\includegraphics{mp-codes/600003.pdf}
\includegraphics{mp-codes/600004.pdf}
\includegraphics{mp-codes/600005.pdf}
\end{document}`

On my Gen 10 with ubuntu 20.04, texlive 2019 it compiles in

real 0m0,492s / user 0m0,076s / sys 0m0,416s

and on Gen 4 with ubuntu 16.04, texlive 2017

real 0m0.242s / user 0m0.222s / sys 0m0.020s

and with more files the difference grows.

Comment: compare the outputs of  `pdflatex --kpathsea-debug=-1` as I say I suspect the slow one is searching a bigger filesystem tree

Comment: Thank you, David.  These are big files and it will take time for me to parse them. AFAICS, there are 3 calls to `kdebug:kpse_find_file: searching for mp-codes/600000.pdf of type tex (from texmf.cnf)` in both cases, and the difference in search trees is just `texlive2019` vs `texlive2017` and `!!` in front of  `/etc/texmf/tex/latex//, /etc/texmf/tex/generic//, /etc/texmf/tex///` in the faster case.

Comment: the !! means it uses a pre cached ls-r file rather than searching the filesystem such a difference is what I had guessed